# Image sizes and order of operations

Tags: images, optimization

I'm working on optimizing my site, and part of that is compressing images and using smaller versions. I'm using WP Smush and creating a bunch of sizes for each image. All images have been smushed.

My template is pretty custom, and I'm not using the normal WYSIWYG in a few places. In those situations, I wrote two functions to pull smaller image sizes as needed:

(note: the first function is from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-to-get-attachment-id-by-image-url)

```
function get_image_id_by_link($link){
    global $wpdb;

    $link = preg_replace('/-\d+x\d+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '', $link);

    return $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE BINARY guid='$link'");
}

function get_image_url($url, $preferred_size = 900){
    $id = get_image_id_by_link($url);

    if(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array($preferred_size, $preferred_size))) {
        return wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array($preferred_size,$preferred_size))[0];
    }
    else if(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(900,900))) {

        return wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(900,900))[0];
    } 
    else if(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'medium_large')){
        return wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'medium_large')[0];
    } 
    else if (wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'large')){
        return wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'large')[0];
    } 
    else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

This function works for any images I upload and use now. But, any images uploaded before I pushed this function always pull the full size image url. I've confirmed that those images (the earlier ones) do have smaller sizes.

While I can re-upload all the images, I'm curious why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

---

Edit

Here are the registered sizes, according to `get_intermediate_image_sizes()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
    [4] => medium-box
    [5] => large-box
    [6] => responsive-100
    [7] => responsive-150
    [8] => responsive-200
    [9] => responsive-300
    [10] => responsive-450
    [11] => responsive-600
    [12] => responsive-900
)
```

Comment: Are all your sizes registered with add_image_size?  Does WP Smush have an option to reprocess older images?

Comment: I think `large` is built in, but I'll try adding a few more to see if that works. I'm unable to find a way to reprocess, but it does look like WP Smush is creating a plethora of image sizes already.

Comment: WP Smush will process all image sizes defined by your theme and plugins using add_image_size as well as the four builtin sizes of thumb, medium, medium_large and large.  If you haven't properly registered your 900x900 image then a 900x900 image won't be generated.

Comment: I see. I'll work on that! Shouldn't this function return the `large` option though?

Comment: Which function? You have two.

Comment: Sorry, the second function that is returning image urls. If the image sizes aren't registered as you said, but large is, then that series of ifs should return the large option, right?

Comment: No - it will return the full uploaded image.  That's default WP behaviour if it can't find the size you've asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` will always return a URL to a file if the image exists in some size.  If the size you ask for doesn't exist then you get the URL for the full size image as uploaded.  (This isn't the "large" image size.)

So, for a valid image ID, your conditional `if(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array($preferred_size, $preferred_size)))` will always succeed, as `wp_get_attachment_image_src` always returns a URL, even if that URL isn't the one you expect.

To fix it, I'd recommend that you don't subvert the API and that you work with it instead.

Comment: Great, thank you! Taking your advice and simplifying it to use the API.